# Facebook Comment Widget Authentication

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I am integrating Facebook comments with a web site. The understanding I have currently editing capabilities can be enabled for certain users by using either of the below mentioned Meta tags on the page:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/></ol>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}">
```

The questions I have are:

1. Can’t the security be bypassed by hosting the widget on a local
   machine with the domain name spoofed using a host file entry?
2. How does this work in case my application is not accessible via internet?

Answer (score 0):

If the Facebook Linter (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint ) can't access your page, you won't be able to set up the administration correctly.
When you first Like the page, post a comment, or manually enter the URL in the Linter, Facebook goes to your page (user agent facebookexternalhit) and reads the tags, including the admins tag. It then allows that user, when logged into Facebook, to admin the comments plugin which will be served to users of your page

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was looking out for. In case I use the "fb:admins" Meta tag to define admin and then decide to add a few more ids after the page has been active for a few days. In that case how long will it take for the new users to be admin. Do I use the lint tool to hit the URL so that Facebook can parse the new metadata?

Comment: If you run it through the linter it updates immediately, otherwise it waits until Facebook updates its cache, which I believe is every 24 hours